# How to show Mongodb's dbs by date?

Tags: mongodb

I know in the mongo shell, I can type `show dbs` to see a list of the databases and their sizes. Is there a way to show the last modified date/time for these databases?

If not, is there a command that shows the latest executed queries across mongo?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be currently no native way to achieve this since mongodb does not store metadata (i.e. last modified) for collections, tables or documents and also doesn't keep an access or transaction log.

The way around would be either to maintain those information manualy (e.g. keep a last modfied fild in every document and manually write log documents for everything you do).

You could also keep an eye the Enterprise edition which now has an [auditing feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/auditing/) but does currently not log the things you want.

Comment: The auditing features of enterprise don't currently (2.6) audit query operations, just administrative-level tasks. The full list is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/audit-message/#audit-action-details-results)

Comment: My bad did not see that. Will edit that. Thought crud would count as `general operations`...